# I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed, i want a windows 7 dual boot, but i dont have windows 7 iso

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-7

Present status: Ubuntu 12.04 installed and working.
Want to install windows 7, keeping it a dual boot.  I have only installation files of Windows 7. What should I do?

Comment: This isn't an answer, but depending on your configuration it will be quite a horrible experience to install Windows 7 AFTER Ubuntu without an ISO. You'd need to 1) handle not having an ISO (what does 'installation files' mean? 2) Partition correctly (easy to mess up), and 3) Reinstall grub (involved). I got an ISO of Windows 7 from MS support one time, when I lost mine--all you need is a key. I recommend reinstalling.

Comment: by installation files i mean, files that have been directly copied from the dvd, I can manage reinstalling the grub and partitioning. I need help with 'not having an iso'.

Comment: Maybe you can try copying the files to USB and making it bootable with some other software? Make an iso and burn to USB as bootable, or something...

Answer (score 1):

First, use gparted to make space for the Windows 7 partition.

After that, you can simply use an ISO with your Windows product key; Microsoft actually makes the ISOs available for download online via [Digital River CDN links](http://indygizmo.com/windows7-direct-download-links-iso-32-64-bit/).

Or, if you don't want to download the ISO, the installation files option will probably have a means of installing to just the empty space, rather than erasing the whole drive (however, I have never used this installation method myself).

After that, you'll want to [boot onto an Ubuntu LiveCD so that you can repair your GRUB installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows).

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can do that by Windows 7 installation files which are let free in a drive. And you have to check with Windows forum for the files you got to get a DVD out of it. But if you got ISO of the windows7, than you can make it a DVD,than by making Partition in UBuntu drive using Gparted, than can install it I believe. Since as far I know, if from Windows installation files, it won't integrative together to form the bootable disk